# Want to use super method to overide the method

Tags: python, odoo

```
@api.model
def systray_get_activities(self):
    # Here we totally override the method. Not very nice, but
    # we should perhaps ask Odoo to add a hook here.
    query = """SELECT m.id, count(*), act.res_model as model,
                    CASE
                        WHEN %(today)s::date -
                        act.date_deadline::date = 0 Then 'today'
                        WHEN %(today)s::date -
                        act.date_deadline::date > 0 Then 'overdue'
                        WHEN %(today)s::date -
                        act.date_deadline::date < 0 Then 'planned'
                    END AS states
                FROM mail_activity AS act
                JOIN ir_model AS m ON act.res_model_id = m.id
                WHERE user_id = %(user_id)s
                AND act.done = False
                GROUP BY m.id, states, act.res_model;
```

I want to inherit this method and add ( AND act.done = False) in this method using super in odoo.

Comment: Already `AND act.done = False` in this method. Are you trying to inherit this method or this is a inherited method?

Comment: i have overide this method and added my line but now i want to use super method not overiding whole method

Comment: you can see this method in mail (module) res_user.py file

Comment: super(your_modelname,self).name_of_method_you_want_to_call(cr,uid,ids, context=context) I think you are asking for this!   you can also use "super().write(vals)" in v13 no need to give class name and self

Comment: I just want to add (AND act.done = False) this after (WHERE user_id = %(user_id)s) for this query  but don't  know how to use super method for this i know the above method but it didn't help me out

Comment: this method you will find in base method I have already written the path can somebody pls help me out with this query method how to use the super method so that I don't have to overwrite the whole method

Comment: It is not possible to modify only one line in method while inheriting it. Either you have to duplicate the whole method Or call original method (super) first then write your logic

Comment: so you mean to say i can't use super method on this